# Identify the PID from a MySQL connection ID?

Tags: mysql

The output from 'mysqladmin processlist' looks like this:

```
+-------+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+------------------------+
| Id    | User | Host      | db    | Command | Time | State             | Info                   |
+-------+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+------------------------+
| 4411  | root | localhost | mydb1 | Sleep   | 86   |                   |                        |
| 12911 | root | localhost | mydb1 | Sleep   | 50   |                   |                        |
| 65142 | root | localhost | mydb1 | Query   | 4    | copy to tmp table | OPTIMIZE TABLE my_tble |
| 65428 | root | localhost |       | Query   | 0    |                   | show processlist   |
+-------+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+-------------------+------------------------+
```

From an 'Id' value in that table, how can I trace back to the PID of the process which created the connection, to figure out who is doing what?  All the connections are via a local socket.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using multiple user accounts. An alternative is to keep a connection history by writing out connection id, process id, script name, and a date/time stamp to a log file or table. I don't know of any other way to track this information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such mapping in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this in my tech blog here: http://blog.fotios.org/2018/02/find-which-process-holds-particular.html

Basically, there's two steps: 1) do a "*show full processlist;*" in mysql; this listing includes the port number of each socket/connection, 2) grep for that number in the "*netstat -np*" output

Comment: Please note that this solution does not work when you make your connection literally via ``localhost``, since mysql client treats ``localhost`` specially and connects using unix socket file, thus omitting TCP/IP. However, when using ``127.0.0.1``, mysql defaults to TCP/IP. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: @MichałSacharewicz The post is not about identifying connections to mysqld from mysql client which is often moot. Regardless, I would think "show full processlist" would still list any unix socket based connections which are then also not excluded from the listing in "netstat -np"